# How To Create Fixed Navigation Bar For All Activities In An Android Application

Tags: android, navigationbar

i want to set a navigation bar ( with two buttons and a textview ) common for all activities of my application. I know it can be done by including a common layout file into each activity's layout file. But i have to use slide transition animation when a activity changes to another. Now if i follow the common layout file including process, then the navigation bar will also slide in or out with the activity's view where i want my navigation bar to be fixed when activities view slides in or out. Besides, the two buttons of the navigation bar should be set as i can hide them by using code to some activities. So now i need help badly on the problem, please give me a solution/suggestion/clue on the problem.Thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) may be what you are looking for in this scenario.

Or thinking about it further maybe [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with multiple layouts could also help in this case.

Comment: Can u explain more briefly how can i do that ... ? :-/

Comment: I have included links in my post above.  Additionally perhaps this could help for viewflippers http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html