# Persistence navigation bar on top of all activities

Tags: android

I'm about to start on an Android project. This app needs to have a (navigation) bar that will be always on top and always visible, also when you switch between activities. The bar must be 10 dp from the bottom and the active activity in the background must be visible above and below to the bar. Is there any component to do this with?

*its lifecycle must remain while switching between activities so it won't slide out of the screen, like the activities do*

Already tried:
Fragments: Only available for > 3.0
Widgets: View is removed when switching between activities
ActivityGroup: Seems to be a bad way

[How To Create Fixed Navigation Bar For All Activities In An Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788198/how-to-create-fixed-navigation-bar-for-all-activities-in-an-android-application)
This seems to be the same question, but no correct answer given.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Fragments in all earlier versions of Android by including the Android Comparability Library and extending FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: Ok, nice. Can the fragment be alive throughout the lifecycle of multiple activities?

Comment: Your other activities would need to exist within another fragment. Here's a good tutorial on the use of Fragments : (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout "ActionBarCompat" example which comes with Android SDK samples for making action bar.
Although this action bar won't let you show background activities.
For showing such action bar on always on top you might want to use System alert .